# Why does JavaScript return different results for RegExp test() method with empty object?

Tags: javascript, regex, object

I recently came across a code snippet (a joke) where the `test()` method of JavaScript's `RegExp` object was used with an empty object as an argument. Here's the code:

```js
console.log(new RegExp({}).test('mom')); // true
console.log(new RegExp({}).test('dad')); // false
```

Can someone explain why is it happens?

Comment: try `console.log(new RegExp({}));` and see if you can figure it out

Comment: It was explained in a comment on the Twitter post.

Comment: dad's get no love! :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a curious fact. [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) accepts a string as its first argument. Since you are passing `{}` it gets coerced to string, and the coercion of an object is the literal string `[object Object]`.

By a fortuitous coincidence, the square brackets have a precise meaning in a regular expression, and it means "one of these characters of the set".

Thus, the regular expression is equal to `[objectO ]`. In other words, your code is equal to:

```
console.log(new RegExp('[object Object]').test('mom'));
```

which is equal to:

```
console.log(new RegExp('[objectO ]').test('mom'));
```

which means: tests `true` if any of these characters is present: o, b, j, e, c, t, O, space. `mom` satisfies this condition, while `dad` doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The `RegExp` constructor casts the first argument to a string. An empty object becomes

```js
new RegExp('[object Object]')
```

Given this represents a [regexp character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), essentially

```js
/[objectO ]/
```

`"mom"` passes because it contains an `"o"`.

Comment: Amazing that the first, equally correct, answer gets no credit.

Comment: @Nick aww thanks. I was even first by almost a minute. Luck of the draw I guess

Comment: Don't buy any lottery tickets! :)